# Cannot use command airmon-ng

Tags: airmon-ng

So when ever I use the command `airmon-ng start wlan0` or just `airmon-ng` I get this error `bash: airmon-ng: command not found`. Ive looked at another form similar to this but it didn't help me.

Comment: What ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu releases don't include the package which contains the command by default, have you installed it?  As already asked though, your OS & release details are requested.

Answer (score 0):

To get this command you have to add *universe* pocket and [install single package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=airmon-ng) from it:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install aircrack-ng
```